# Using AjaxToolKit for improved WebForm Login

Tags: asp.net, roundedcorners-dropshadow

I chose AjaxToolKit to build a WebForm login. Has anyone else had problems trying to do this? I'm planning to use DropShadow Extender and RoundedCorners with Panels, but this is my first time working with panels.

Please check [this link](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx).

I want to put a login panel into something like the screenshot shows, whenever the user clicks a button. This would be similar functionality to what happens on StackOverflow when you try to insert an image or hyperlink in 'ask a question'. Is this possible? How much effort is it?

Comment: may want to clean up your link markdown

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about 100% using ajax control toolkit, check out the [ModalPanel](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) example.

You could also go for a javascript library option like [iBox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/), which would be a bit harder to integrate, but not much.

I much prefer doing this manually with javascript and css, if you know what you are doing it is not that hard, if you aren't familiar with those technologies it may take more work. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/10/25/Modal_2D00_style-pops-in-Javascript-and-CSS.aspx) is a good post that walks you through the basics

Answer (score 0):

I use AjaxControlToolkit extensively in my application and its really simple.Being server side ajax I does emit a lot of javascript on your page. I suggest you use AJAX only where its required i.e. in cases where a page does lots of things and you want to make it more responsive something like a Dashboard kind of app.

Comment: Did you find a demo, or just build it based on ajaxtoolkit website? my main cue is how to insert a panel into a modalpanel